# How to replace qt.conf?

Tags: qt

I'm working on an embedded system.  The directory `/root/txpa/images/current/application/bin` contains the file `qt.conf`, the content of which looks like this:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=/qtdir
Libraries=/qtdir/lib
```

`/qtdir/lib/fonts` is about the only thing in the path, and it contains several fonts of kind `Vera`.  These are the only fonts in the system, and the app itself doesn't use them directly.  Qt does.

I've been asked to remove `qt.conf` from its current directory, but if I do the app doesn't start (I suppose Qt can't find any fonts).  How would i do this?  I've read about Qt resource system, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps I had to follow in order to resolve this problem:

First, create a `qt_conf.qrc` file that looks like this:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
>   <qresource prefix="/qt/etc/">
>     <file>qt.conf</file>
>   </qresource>
> </RCC>
> ```

QLibraryInfo will load `qt.conf` from `:/qt/etc/qt.conf` using the resource system.  That should explain the above `qt_conf.qrc`.

Second, copy the `qt.conf` file to the same directory as the `qt_conf.qrc` file (this can be changed, of course).

And finally, update the `*.pro` files, if any, and rebuild.  The original `qt.conf` file can be removed from the directory that it was in.

Comment: I confused steps A, B and C to be alternatives, not steps to be taken one after the other. Would it make more sense to make it 1, 2 and 3 instead?

Comment: @MarcusOttosson sorry about the confusion.  I've made changes to my answer, and hopefully it's less confusing now.

Comment: This works great when there is only 1 resource file, but I don't know how to do it when there is more than 1 resource file... it doesn't seem to find the path